# How to Substitute or Replace All Characters but NOT those inside quotes? (Google Sheets)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Hy guys,

I was trying to substitute "spaces" with commas but if in the cell I have this:

*"e commerce" shop*

the result I'm obtaining is:

"e,commerce",shop

I'm using this formula: 
=SUBSTITUTE(A2:A, " ", ",")

Also tried with the REGEX method, but to be honest, I'm quite a noobie on that(!)

---

Do you think is possible to obtain that while excluding text that's inside "quotes"?

So, using the previous example:

**"e commerce",shop**

Thanks a lot, hope it's a doable thing

Have an Awesome day,

Elia

---

As required, here's some examples:

INPUT ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  OUTPUT

"e commerce" "search engine" -> "e commerce","search engine"

"keyword research" SEO -> -> "keyword research",SEO

"search engine" audit professional -> "search engine",audit,professional

"keyword research" SEO -> -> "keyword research",SEO

"we are looking" consultant -> -> "we are looking",consultant

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply,
here's some examples:

INPUT    ->     ->     ->     ->     ->     ->  OUTPUT
"e commerce" "search engine"   ->       "e commerce","search engine"
"keyword research" SEO    ->     ->      "keyword research",SEO
"search engine" audit professional   ->  "search engine",audit,professional
"keyword research" SEO   ->     ->        "keyword research",SEO
"we are looking" consultant   ->     ->     "we are looking",consultant

As I saw the comment is displayed bad formatted, hope it's clearer from here:
cl.ly/3N1x2c3Z1q44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"("".*?""|\w+)?(\s)(\w+|"".*?"")","$1,$3")
```

- `$1` Optional Capture group enclosed by `"` or `\w`ords
- `$2` `\s`pace outside `"` to be replaced by `,`
- `$3` Multiple `\w`ords `|` Capture group enclosed by `"`

Comment: Awesome solution, thanks a lot.

I just tried it with almost few hundred cells, I saw that if the words inside quotes are not the first words, like in these examples: "e commerce" "search engine" OR SEO "search engine" , the formula keep a space between them.
Or, another example, with this input: "e commerce" searching "search engine" - output: "e commerce",searching "search,engine".

Any thoughts?
Maybe I'm missing something :)
Thanks again!